# How to change the direction of the arrow (tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

When I write this code:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.1-1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state] (1) {$1$};
\path[->](1) edge [loop] ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I get is this:
[image]

How I repace the direction of the arrow to left to right?

Thank you!

Comment: `\path(1) edge [in=60,out=120,loop] ();` and please clean up your code, i.e. remove all unnecessary packages.

Comment: I edit my code :-) It's still no the same... :-( I get other shape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state] (1) {$1$};
\path(1) edge [in=45,out=135,looseness=8,loop] ();
\node[state] (2) at (2,0) {$2$};
\path(2) edge [loop] ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can do that it will be at the same shape (like at example)?

Comment: @heblyx Yes, one only needs to look up the definitions of `loop` in `tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex`.